# Is this question acceptable now, or further improvement needed?

Tags: discussion

I wrote a question that I don't believe was actually subjective, but I phrased the title in such a way that it might have sounded so to anyone not familiar enough with the technology to realize that my asking whether there was a "more proper" way to do something was really a yes/no question and not an invitation for opinions.

I've updated it... hopefully it will be reopened soon. But I thought I'd check here for additional feedback in case I could/should improve it further to encourage reopening.

Here is the question: [Can DI be implemented in Xamarin Forms w/o using a Service Locator pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62651403/can-di-be-implemented-in-xamarin-forms-w-o-using-a-service-locator-pattern).

Comment: I’ve only read the title; but it’s usually better to pose questions as “how to” instead of yes/no questions.

Comment: @Yivi Thanks! I've updated it to say how since, if the answer is yes, obviously I wanted to know how also.

Comment: Showing some research into DI patterns other than Service Locator would be nice... A search on "dependency injection xamarin forms" returns about 146,000 hits; it's hard to believe that you could find nothing in all of those results, including [the official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection)...

Comment: Maybe someone with a lot of experience with Xamarin can see it well scoped... currently it feels way too broad for SO - showing particular piece of code that you need help with (presumably around creation of top level form/page) would likely make question more scoped.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have read the article you mentioned. It's focused on how to use DI between the main Forms project and the Android/iOS/UWP projects. In MVC, you can hook into what is, behind the scenes, a service locator to make your DI resolve your controller; but there is no analogous generation of objects when navigating in MVVM. No one questions this being done behind the scenes in MVC, yet if you do it yourself in MVVCM it's "bad" so I'm trying to figure out if there is actually even another way to do it or not.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, exactly. I would expect someone who would answer to be knowledgeable about this and that's who the target audience of the question is... not someone who isn't. I wasn't really planning to write a college paper to get my question answered though. If that's the effort I have to put into it then I guess I won't worry about it.